# binding to TextView

Tags: android, textview, simplecursoradapter

I've tried all the  examples in this site that talk about binding data to a TextView
but nothing solve my problem .

I have a dataBase, and TextView , I bind them together with a simple cursor adapter

```
        MyDataBase mDB = new MyDataBase(this);
        Cursor cursor = mDB.all(this);

        String[] from = new String[] {mDB.VALUE};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.text1View1};

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main, cursor, from , to );
        adapter.setViewBinder(new myViewBinder());
```

and here is the code of the myViewBinder

```
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

    TextView txtWelcome = (TextView) view;
    String name = cursor.getString(VALUE_ID);
    txtWelcome.setText(name);
}
```

can any one help me to know why there's no change in the main activity when it's lunched?
what extra code I need to add ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after setting the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I believe for this to work you would have to be able to set the SimpleCursorAdapter as the adapter on the TextView but the TextView class doesn't support that operation out of the box.